# Check if variable is of a custom type in Erlang?

Tags: types, erlang, typechecking, custom-type

Is there a way to check if a variable is of a custom type in Erlang?

Suppose I have some records and types defined in an `.hrl` file:

```
-record(custom_record, {
    attr1 :: list(),
    attr2 :: binary(),
    attr3 :: tuple()
}).

-record(another_record, {
    attr1 :: list(),
    attr2 :: binary(),
}).

-type custom_record() :: #custom_record{}.

-type another_record() :: #another_record{}.

-type custom_records() :: custom_record() | another_record().
```

Is there an easy way to check if a record is a `custom_record` in my Erlang code? Something like this would be nice:

```
is_custom_type(CustomRecord, custom_records). %=> true
```

I looked through the docs and didn't see any build-in functions that did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no custom types in Erlang. Records are just syntactic sugar for tuples tagged with the atom and of the same length. Typespecs are used solely by dialyzer and nothing else.

Answer (score 7):

The Erlang standard library contains the `is_record()` BIF, that checks if the first element of a tuple is the appropriate atom, see [is_record/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_record-2) so you can test your variable like `is_record(Var, custom_record)`.

Comment: Even better is `is_record/3`, at least if you know the sizes of all records you are using, since it doesn't need to know the record definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pattern matching for this purpose:

```
is_custom_type(#custom_record{} = _Record) -> true;
is_custom_type(_) -> false.
```

Comment: The disadvantage to this is that a function clause will be required for every record that is part of that type. In my example there were only two records, but in parts of my code there are quite a few.

Comment: Then how a function your are asking for would help you?